# Regular Expressions Phone number must not start with 555

Tags: java, regex, validation, numbers

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchPhoneNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sPhoneNumber = "5568889999";
        // String sPhoneNumber = "605-88899991";
        // String sPhoneNumber = "605-888999A";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?![5][5][5]).*$&\\d([2-9]{9})");
        // Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[^555]\\d{7}|\\d([2-9]{9})");

        // ^[^0-9]+$
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sPhoneNumber);

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form XXXXXXXXXX");
        }
    }
}
```

I want this to return Phone number valid when I enter 556 and false only if the first 3 digits are 555. 
Also I do not want the first digit to be a 0 or a 1 
How do I achieve this?

Comment: `^(?!555)[2-9]\d{8}$`?

Comment: What about any other digits in the first 3 places? Is 666 a valid number phone number? What about 2000000000?

Comment: okay so ^(?!555)[2-9]\d{8}$ returns the wrong output for a correct phone number. so that's wrong. and yes 2000000000 will count as a correct phone number for now. But, I don't understand how to add multiple conditions to the same regular expression.  So, effectively, the number should have 10 characters(which can be any from 0-9), the first number cannot be 0 or 1  and the first three digits cannot be 5. How to put this all into one regular expression? 666 will not count as a valid phone number. It has to be 10 characters(numbers) because the number is inputted as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match your number format you could use:

[`^(?![01]|555)\d{10}$`](https://regex101.com/r/sRUw7a/1)

In Java:

`^(?![01]|555)\\d{10}$`

That would match:

- `^` Begin of the string
- `(?!` Negative lookahead that asserts what follows is not

  - `[01]` Match 0 or 1
  - `|` or
  - `555` Match literally
- `)` Close negative lookahead
- `\d{10}` Match 10 digits
- `$` The end of the string

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/QYKFME68843)